# Apache Spark read multiple text files in single run

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, text-files

I can successfully load a text file into a DataFrame with the following Apache Spark Scala code:

```
val df = spark.read.text("first.txt")
  .withColumn("fileName", input_file_name())
  .withColumn("unique_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Is there any way to provide the multiple files in the single run? Something like this:

```
val df = spark.read.text("first.txt,second.txt,someother.txt")
  .withColumn("fileName", input_file_name())
  .withColumn("unique_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Right now the following code doesn't work with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:first.txt,second.txt,someother.txt;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
```

How to properly load multiple text files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `spark.read.text()` have a varargs parameter, from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader):

> `def text(paths: String*): DataFrame`

This means that to read multiple files you only need to supply them to the function separated by commas, i.e.

```
val df = spark.read.text("first.txt", "second.txt", "someother.txt")
```